# Что означает данный селектор $("#"+ajax_form)?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Есть форма.

```
<form id="ajax_form"></form>
```

И Ajax запрос.

```
$.ajax({
    data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize()
});
```

Тоже самое что и `$("#ajax_form")` ???

Comment: а конкатенацию двух строки `#` и переменной `ajax_form` вы здесь не видите совсем?

Comment: Смысл тогда этой записи?

Answer (score 0):

Смысл записи

```
$("#"+ajax_form)
```

в том что в функцию `$` будет передан селектор с именем состоящим из `#` и значения переменной `ajax_form`.

Например, если где-то есть

```
var ajax_form = "mySuperSelector";`
```

то вы получите

```
$('#mySuperSelector')
```

И будет искаться элемент с `id="mySuperSelector"`.

Почему и кто написал такое - мы здесь разбираться не будем. Вероятно, это просто опечатка и код должен быть просто:

```
$("#ajax_form")
```

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Думал может есть какое то более существенное различие,  решил уточнить ;)